# test case failure while running through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, pyspark, pytest

I am running a set of unit test cases using pytest through Jenkins. I am able to run the test cases in local but in Jenkins its throwing an error. I am not able to understand the root cause. Can anyone please help me with this? I am attaching the error message.

```
 ____________________ ERROR at setup of test_npm_hh_demos_tc ____________________

    request = <SubRequest 'spark_context' for <Function 'test_npm_hh_demos_tc'>>

        @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
        def spark_context(request):
            conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("pytest-pyspark-local-testing"))
            request.addfinalizer(lambda: sc.stop())
    >       sc = SparkContext(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

    /temp/workspace/ON-Pipeline_feature_rahul_test12/extracts/src/test/conftest.py:13: 
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
    /tmf_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py:115: in __init__
        SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    /tmf_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py:292: in _ensure_initialized
        SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)

/tmf_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py:93: Exception
---------------------------- Captured stderr setup -----------------------------
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID 25198
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID 1009100
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID 25198
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for user ID 1009100
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.  Program will exit
```

Comment: Seems like an issue with the versions of java you have. Check jre version on both your machine and jenkins and make sure they are the same.

Comment: There is no version mismatch. I have checked it already.